# Can you "nest" modules in python?

Tags: python, module, pygame, nested

I'm working with a pygame tutorial and I'm importing the pygame module on a separate file from my main.py.

pygame.py:

```
    import pygame

class Game:

    def __init__(self):
```

main.py:

```
from game import Game

def main():
```

I'm guessing I already have my answer, since I keep receiving the error: "NameError: name 'pygame' is not defined", but is there any way to nest modules without importing them into your main? Not a big deal, just thought I'd ask.

Comment: You'll get the error "NameError: name 'pygame' is not defined" only if you try to use the module `pygame` in the _main_ module

Answer (score 1):

You might access imported modules inside imported modules following way

*mymodule.py*

```
import math
class Math:
    pass
```

*main.py*

```
import mymodule
print(mymodule.math.cos(0.0))
```

then running `python main.py` output

```
1.0
```

Comment: I see, so you can't call the math module as you normally would, you'd have to call the file name module, then the math module, then the class/function. That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Hum, I tried that and while it does allow me to initialize pygame, I now cannot define the class in that file module.